# Spring websockets tcp -> flow controll interface

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-security, spring-websocket, flow-control

I have a spring boot app that is leveraging websockets. I have build my own protocol that is being transported over websockets in binary. Now in that protocol after certain even has occurred I would like to use flow control in order to signalize the client that he needs to slow down. 
Since i am already using websockets and websockets is leveraging TCP, I would like to use the TCP flow control mechanism that is already build  within TCP. I do not want to reinvent the wheel myself. Does anyone knowns how I can control the TCP window size during my websocket connection in Spring. I.e. is there some specific interface that can provide me this mechanism?

All according to RFC 6455 i.e working with the  Sec-WebSocket-Extensions header and websocket Status Codes.